# REGEX: Special Characters detected for [[a-zA-Z0-9]]

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I built a filter with the rule: [[a-zA-Z0-9]]
So the intention was that content with at least a number or a letter and should remove content with special characters for example "?" and ":)" or any other emojis.
So far it worked great, however i noticed that the rule does not worked for symbols that starts with the unicode "U+1" and seems to recognize as a letter or a number. Other special letters/symbols starting with "U+0" for example ◌́ seems to work as intended.

Can somebody please explain the reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: Wrapping character classes in `[[ ... ]]` doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing by posting the code where you are using the regex in?

Comment: So i am currently using a software to gather Facebook post on my page - it could have user text in the post but also post with emojis, gifs and picture - with the software i can include a rule which says "Post Message" REGEX and i could enter a REGEX rule like [a-zA-Z0-9] - for some reason the software would enter [[a-zA-Z0-9]]....

Comment: the rule [a-zA-Z0-9] should forward all message to me with the intention to get post with text but not gifs, pictures and so on ... which is working great except for specific characters/letters/symbol and i only found the common attribute was the Unicode beginning of "U+1". And i am also not quite sure if that is an issue based on the software or based on the rule or maybe based on Facebook itself?

Comment: Kim, could show some examples in a table with the columns input, desired output, actual output? And could you name the used regex library?